# I mounted my raid and it didnt worked

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, samba, raid

I mounted my raid to the /media/sdb1 mount point that I created earlyer. After that, I opend the smb.conf and the added the mount point to the path.

```
  [share]
  comment = Arthur Server
  path = /media/sdb1
  writeable = yes
  browseable = yes
  public = yes
  create mask = 0644
  directory mask = 0755
  force user = arthur
```

But if I upload now things, it saves them on my ssd in the mountpoint folder. How can I solve this issue? or is that how mounting works??

Thats how my fstab looks like.

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
    #
    # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
    # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
    # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
    #
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=2c3a1f8c-5aa8-4e7b-a0fa-b19a33b8b647 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
    # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
    UUID=1f6f9d2a-d99b-470b-be5d-b849c94c5f4a none            swap    sw              0  
#device        mountpoint             fstype    options  dump   fsck

/dev/md0    /media/sdb1    ext4    defaults    0    1     0
```

Thanks in advance, Arthur

Comment: Just to make sure, is the raid automounted via fstab for example or do you have to mount it manually. if this a yes are you restarting the samba server?

Comment: I added my fstab file in the Question on top. I couldn't find out if it was automounted. If you need anymore informations, just ask.

Comment: It looks like there is no raid being automounted in fstab. You could start from there by making sure it mounta automatically then work on the samba part.

Comment: So I automounted my drive now. Now I can't add anything to the server from the Windows File explorer. How do I need to change ther smb.conf to access the raid?

Comment: Did you verify that after rebooting it automounts? (Just to be sure). If yes, then just in case, when you say "Windows File explorer" do you literally mean Microsoft Windows or are you talking about the file explorer on Ubuntu (Dolphin, Nautilus, File, etc..). If it's the former, then you would need to make sure that the format that the partition has is fat32 or NTFS to make it compatible between both systems (Linux and Windows). If it's the latter, make sure you have the correct permissions, or simply go crazy and do a chmod 0777 on the partition if this will be locally used for you only.

Comment: Ty the chmod 0777 worked :D

Comment: excellent work. I have added your testing to an answer. You are welcome to edit anything in there if it's missing something else. Great work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Arthur, the steps to make sure that you can mount a RAID partition and also use it are:

- Make sure that the RAID is added to `/etc/fstab`
- Make sure that the permissions are correctly set (eg: `chmod 0777 /RAID/PATH`)
- Make sure that the information about the partition has been correctly added to the Samba configuration file (eg: `smb.conf`)

All steps provided by Arthur